# Error trying to launch EC2 instance, the M6gd is not an available option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting this error when trying to launch an EC2 instance.

"the M6gd is not an available option"

What causes such an error, and how to resolve it? Please help.

Comment: Those are only available in 4 regions right now I believe. What region are you trying to create them in?

Comment: Where can I find these regions list? I am actually working for a client who is trying to do this on her own. So I don't know which region she's using, but maybe I can tell her which regions are available.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/announcing-new-amazon-ec2-instances-powered-aws-graviton2-processors/